# Sorting and print out 2d array base on user input

Tags: c++, arrays

i have create a 2d array program and i am trying to print out the array base on user choice

This is the array

```
 1 2 3
1a b c
2d e f
3g h i
```

If the user key in 1b3, it will show
adgbehcfi

if c21 is enter, it will show
cfibehadg

Right now i have create the array, however im stuck with how to print out the order of the array base on user input,please help me. Thank you.

After spending some day doing, below are my code

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string alphabate;
    string array[3][3];
    string a="abcdefghi";

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        array[i][j] = a[j+ (i * 3)];
    }
}

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        cout << array[i][j];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

cout << "Enter some alphabate:";
cin >>alphabate;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate 1b1 abd c21

Comment: they refer to column first column is 1, 2 is b since b is the second in alphabetical order follow by 3rd column.I made an error, it is 1b3

Comment: "im stuck with how to read the array" looks like you know `cin` already, so what is the problem ?

Comment: @Happy In 1b3 , 1 means column 1, b means column 2 and 3 means column 3.Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Sumeet Singh yes you are right.

Comment: @Happy Shouldn't the input be `string a="abcdefghi";`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you want to print the array elements based only on the column number/index that user have entered. This is how I realized that. Hope that helps :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string array[3][3];

//function that prints the column c of the array
void printArray(int c) {
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        cout << array[i][c];
    }
}

int main() {

    string alphabate;
    string a="abcdefghi";

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
            array[i][j] = a[j+ (i * 3)];
        }
    }

    cout << "Enter some alphabate:";
    cin >> alphabate;

    //checking the input parameters
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        if (alphabate[j] == '1' || alphabate[j] == 'a') {
            printArray(0);
        }
        else if (alphabate[j] == '2' || alphabate[j] == 'b') {
            printArray(1);
        }
        else if (alphabate[j] == '3' || alphabate[j] == 'c') {
            printArray(2);
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error";
        }
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, however i spend some time for trying to solve two more things. I have update them in the question. Thank you once again.

Comment: I could update my question, so i will post here. The first thing is how can i make my program smarter like making the cin>>alphabate to be more logical like accept 1234 and reject input that are not in order like 1(missing 2)34.
The other thing is how can i make my program to accept array like 10 words. I notice if i key in helloworld the cipher text is missing out the letter d in the 2d array. Once again im grateful for you help. Thank you

Comment: hi, i forgot to add, i did make the array to be array[5][5] and end up getting garbage value for those missing field in unix environment.